# Ubuntu cannot start from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, tty, startup, x-server

Ubuntu 12.04
By a mistake, I stopped lightdm. Then switched to tty1, and rebooted.
Now, After startup, It just came a black screen with a cursor, can type nothing.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>), nothing works.

There might be something wrong with X server (Because I cannot type in, there is no way to try `startx`)

Comment: To me it seems you are having a problem booting. Did you see any message from grub before the blank screen with the blinking cursor at all? (BTW you could just have done `/etc/init.d/lightdm restart` instead of rebooting)

Comment: @Anthon Grub seems work normally.  Maybe only reinstall the OS could save me

Comment: If grub starts, try select `Linux 3.2.0.... (recovery mode)` that should show you where the machine stops

Comment: Edit your grub at the boot menu (you can see the hotkeys there), and remove **quiet splash** from there. You will find them. Then press the button which will boot the system. Finally, read the error. Or make a photo of it.